# Why to use TIMESTAMP instead of INT value?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the pros and cons of the various date/time field types in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469846/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-various-date-time-field-types-in-mysql)

In many database, I saw they use `TIMESTAMP` type to store time value, my question is why don't use `INT` type to store `$date->getTimestamp()` value and then we could get time value easier?

Comment: what do you mean by "easier", timestamp - is not simple enough ?

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to MySQL databases. One reason is that the RDBMS has [lots of internal functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) designed for indexing and processing dates.

Answer (score 7):

Because when you treat a date as a date, and not as a number, you can do neat stuff like adding durations (DATE+1MONTH-1HOUR). `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` etc are also optimized for dates, and will do native validation for you.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons, I'd say the most obvious (and straight forward one) is that the databse *knows* that the value is a `TIMESTAMP` (so Date/Time related), which is not the case for an `INT`.

This has several consequences, for example that Mysql is aware of timezones and automatically concerts the `TIMESTAMP` to UTC. That means the data is much more concrete, because it is clear what the data means. For the `INT` types you would need to take care of that your own, it would not be relative to the database any longer.

The next big difference is automatic initialization and updating. That means, if the row is inserted or changed, a `TIMESTAMP` column will get "stamped" with the current time.

There are several other differences then as well between these types, most of the are related to data/time functions. I suggest you dig into:

- [11.3.1. The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do many more things in the database when using a timestamp instead of a plain number. Query by day of week, group by month, determine intervals, etc...

Answer (score 1):

An int is only 4 bytes a datetime is 8 bytes so you'd have less possible values. In particular for php you are getting Unix timestamps which have a min date 1901-12-13, and max of 2038-01-19. This is essentially going back and making the same sort of decisions that lead to the Y2K problem. Assuming you can live with that you should be okay but what about non-Unix based hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Because actual representation of data does not have to be exposed. Why?

- flexibility (internal representation of data may change any time and user won't depend on it).
- reliability (database may check data for consistency if it knows what the data is)
- readability (there's no reason to treat a timestamp as integer, it shows the meaning of a record)

Answer (score 1):

The reason there are different number types (such as timestamp), is to provide data integrity.

Data Integrity makes sure that we don't accidentally put in the number of waffles we had for breakfast :)

If we try to put in an invalid timestamp, MySQL will throw an error and prevent us from putting in bad data.